# Linq-to-SQL Grouping not ordering correctly

Tags: linq-to-sql, t-sql, grouping

Hi can someone help me convert this tsql statement into c# linq2sql?

```
select [series] from table group by [series] order by max([date]) desc
```

This is what i have so far - the list is not in correct order..

```
            var x = from c in db.Table
                    orderby c.Date descending 
                    group c by c.Series into d
                    select d.Key;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ `orderby` clause isn't doing the same thing as your SQL one. Here, this should fix it:

```
var query = from c in db.Table
            group c by c.Series into d
            orderby d.Max(item => item.Date) descending
            select d.Key;
```